# Is java 9 and above still platform independent or not?

Tags: java, deployment

I am asking this question because now developer needs to compile his code on different OS like windows, Linux, or Mac OS to create the final deliverable. It looks bigger overhead for developers.

Comment: What "final deliverable" are you talking about?

Comment: *"now developer needs to compile his code on different OS"* Who told you this?

Comment: You are right I should have used packaged instead of compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have misunderstood the [Self-Contained Application Packaging](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/deploy/self-contained-application-packaging.htm#JSDPG583) ability of Java 9 that looks set to replace Java Web Start as a deployment tool for desktop apps.

JWS used a plain Jar as the deliverable but required that a Java Runtime Environment on the user machine already be installed. On the other hand, the packaging tool will wrap that Jar into an executable suitable for Windows (a .exe) or Unix (a .so) etc. To do so, it would require that the native executable has the parts of the JRE coded for each system (Jars are platform independent but JREs need to be made for each OS).

If you deliver an executable Jar to the user (and inform them they need the Java plug-in installed, to run it), then that Jar will still be compatible for all OS on which Java is supported.

Comment: Well you are right that Self-Contained Application Packaging is definitely giving us a nice solution to get rid of bulky JRE's that we were downloading and installing till java 8. But, I have mentioned here this as an overhead for developers because everyone does not have Linux and Mac OS on their machines. So, I think it would be better to have some kind of tool/docker image/virtual box image which could contain all OS and run these packaging tool to ease up developers jobs.

Comment: *"Well you are right that Self-Contained Application Packaging is definitely giving us a nice solution to get rid of bulky JRE's that we were downloading and installing till java 8."* You are reading too much into what I wrote. I have no opinion on whether it is 'nice'.  It just is the way Oracle has decided. *"But, I have mentioned here this as an overhead for developers because everyone does not have Linux and Mac OS on their machines"* Why would they have to? ..

Comment: .. *"So, I think it would be better to have some kind of tool/docker image/virtual box image which could contain all OS and run these packaging tool to ease up developers jobs."* Think whatever you want. But this is a Q&A site, not an .. advocacy and opinion forum. Your **question** has been answered.

Answer (score 2):

Yes of course it is still platform independent.

Java Bytecode does not change between Windows, Linux or Mac OS.

You can take the class files compiled on windows, or a Jar file with classes inside, and copy them to a Linux or Mac OS machine, and they will work, as long as the platform's major version is the same or later than that of the one where they were originally compiled.

So if they were compiled with a Java 9 compiler targeting a Java 9 runtime, the platform executing them will need to be Java 9 or later. Otherwise you would get an `UnsupportedClassVersionError`.

Answer (score 0):

java is platform independent but java runtime environment(jre) isn't.

so, if developer want to provide product for various platform without installing jre in user's environment,
the product should contain different jre for each platform.

+) compilation doesn't matter, it needs to be done just once.